# Converting Google+ date into indian time zone

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I get this error:

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

When I covert Google plus date to India time zone. I use this code:

```
private static DateTime Getdate(string published)
{
    return DateTime.ParseExact(published, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well. Uh. Is `published` a date according to the format MM/dd/yyyy?

Comment: is `published` a valid DateTime string ? when forming a DateTime use the constructor, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x you can avoid errors by specifiy the year, date and month if you know them

Comment: @VigneshNatraj Well, I suspect OP doesn't know them, which is why they're using a parsing method.

Comment: Got a  this error  String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. And published datetime format is( 2012-09-13T05:08:03.151Z)

Comment: I have a goggle plus datetime like 2012-09-13T05:08:03.151Z and i convert this date into india time zone

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of the DateTime.ParseExact method must match the format of the first argument. Try to change your code like this:

```
private static DateTime Getdate(string published)
{
    return DateTime.ParseExact(published, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ", New CultureInfo("hi-IN"));
}
```

Comment: 2012-09-13T05:08:03.151Z can u help me that this one comes from which time zone and country

Comment: This code help me and here i got a different of 24 hours of Indian time how can i make remove difference of time thanks

Comment: private static DateTime Getdate(string published)
{
    return DateTime.ParseExact(published, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
} this code help me but i want to change in too Indian time zone

Comment: I edited the previous code changing the last parameter of the ParseExact method, try it now.

Comment: I have a date field in this here it give me kind unspecify how can i change it in c#